# How to exit the slot function safely when open file failed

Tags: qt

Here is a slot function like this:

```
void frmMain::on_btnDownload_clicked()
{
       ...//part 1

        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
           dataArray=file.readAll();
        }
        else
        {
            //What to do here?
        }
        ...//part 2
}
```

When calling open() , I hope it will succeed. So that , part 2 , which is the main function body of these code , will be executed.

But sometimes it fails. So I hope to exit this slot and waiting to clicked the button again to call this slot. Then I can try to open this file for the second time.

I don't know why the return value of Qt slot function is **void**. Which means I can't use `return -1` to exit my function. So what should I do when handling open files in Qt? Should I put part 2 into the `if` scope such as:

```
 void frmMain::on_btnDownload_clicked()
  {
       ...//part 1

        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
           dataArray=file.readAll();
           ...//part 2
        }
        else
        {
            //What to do here?
        }

}
```

Comment: If your file opening fails, do nothing - the execution will go out of your function's scope. Otherwise, you can explicitly exit with calling `return` without arguments, because your function is `void`, i.e returns nothing.

Comment: Or if you want to know when this slot failed you can create Signal and Slot for example: Signal: `void errorFileOpeningSignal();` , slot: `void gotErrorWithOpeningFile();` Connect it together and in your example: `if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
        {
           dataArray=file.readAll();
           ...//part 2
        }
        else
        {
            emit errorFileOpeningSignal();
        }`